# Riverpod Initialize a notifier based on another state

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I want to implement a simple to-do app. I have two entities: Groups and Tasks, where each group can have multiple tasks.
I have two providers:

groups_provider.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:todo/models/group.dart';
import 'package:todo/db/db_helper.dart' as dbHelper;
import 'package:todo/providers/tasks_provider.dart';

class GroupsNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<Group>> {
  GroupsNotifier() : super([]);

  void loadGroups() async {
    state = await dbHelper.getAllGroups();
  }

  void addGroup(String title, Color color) async {
    final newId = await dbHelper.addGroup(title, color);
    final newGroup = Group(id: newId, title: title, color: color);

    state = [...state, newGroup];
  }
}

final groupsProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<GroupsNotifier, List<Group>>((ref) {
  return GroupsNotifier();
});
```

and
tasks_provider.dart

```
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:todo/models/group.dart';
import 'package:todo/models/task.dart';
import 'package:todo/db/db_helper.dart' as dbHelper;
import 'package:todo/providers/groups_provider.dart';

class TasksNotifier extends StateNotifier<Map<Group, List<Task>>> {
  TasksNotifier() : super({});

  void loadTasks(Group group) async {
    state = {...state, group: await dbHelper.getTasksByGroup(group)};
  }

  void addTask(String title, Group group, bool done) async {
    final newId = await dbHelper.addTask(title, group, done);
    final newTask = Task(id: newId, title: title, group: group, done: done);

    state = {
      ...state,
      group: [...state[group] ?? [], newTask]
    };
  }

  void toggleDone(Task task) {
    final group = task.group;
    final List<Task> tasks = state[group]!;

    final index = tasks.indexOf(task);
    List<Task> newList = [];
    bool newValue = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < state.length; i++) {
      newValue = index == i ? !tasks[i].done : tasks[i].done;
      newList.add(
        Task(
            id: tasks[i].id,
            title: tasks[i].title,
            group: tasks[i].group,
            done: newValue),
      );
    }
    dbHelper.changeTaskDone(task, newValue);
    state = {...state, group: newList};
  }
}

final tasksProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<TasksNotifier, Map<Group, List<Task>>>((ref) {
  return TasksNotifier();
});
```

I use `sqflite` to work with SQLite database.

Because reading from database is an **async** task

```
class _TasksInCardState extends ConsumerState<TasksInCard> {
  List<Task> tasks = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    ref.read(tasksProvider.notifier).loadTasks(widget.group);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    tasks = ref.watch(tasksProvider)[widget.group]??[];

    return Expanded(
      child: Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
        child: ListView.builder(
....
```

tasks in first call is []

[image]

Generally, how can I implement this one-to-many relationship with Riverpod.

Comment: What is the problem exactly ? Your code looks alright.

Comment: The literature is rushing to catch up with Remi's prolific development.  In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

Comment: Instead of having a `TasksNotifier`, I would suggest having a `GroupTasksNotifier` with a family based on the group. This would simplify a lot

Comment: @ndelanou first time the app loaded, tasks for first group are empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it will fix your issue but you could change :

```dart
void loadTasks(Group group) async {
  state = {...state, group: await dbHelper.getTasksByGroup(group)};
}
```

to:

```dart
void loadTasks(Group group) async {
  final groupTasks = await dbHelper.getTasksByGroup(group);
  state = {...state, group: groupTasks};
}
```

Or using a family provider:

```dart
class GrouTasksNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<Task>> {
  final Group group;

  GrouTasksNotifier(this.group) : super(const []);

  Future<void> loadTasks() async {
    state = await dbHelper.getTasksByGroup(group);
  }

  Future<void> addTask(String title, bool done) async {
    final newId = await dbHelper.addTask(title, group, done);
    final newTask = Task(id: newId, title: title, group: group, done: done);

    state = [...state, newTask];
  }

  void toggleDone(Task task) {
    final newValue = !task.done;
    dbHelper.changeTaskDone(task, newValue);
    final updatedState = state.map((t) {
      if (t.id == task.id) {
        return Task(
          id: task.id,
          title: task.title,
          group: task.group,
          done: newValue,
        );
      } else {
        return t;
      }
    }).toList();

    state = updatedState;
  }
}

final groupTasksProvider = StateNotifierProvider.family<GrouTasksNotifier, List<Task>, Group>((ref, group) {
  return GrouTasksNotifier(group);
});
```

Comment: What's the difference between them?

Comment: You have some concurrency running when displaying multiple groups simultaneously.
The `loadTasks` method is called multiple times, and the `state` getter is called before the execution of the `dbHelper` method. Resulting on overriding every group data except the last one.

Comment: As mentioned in my comment under the question, you should use a `GroupTasksNotifier`of type `StateNotifier<List<Tasks>>` with a provider of type `StateNotifierProvider.family<GroupTasksNotifier, List<Tasks>, Group>`

Comment: Your answer worked and the problem solved. I really appreciate and I'll try your suggestion about `StateNotifierProvider.family`

Comment: @MojtabaMahamed Updated answer with the code for the mentioned provider

Comment: The family approach also worked. Great, thanks.